# Strange Behavior-Did select row touch not responding for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a very strange problem,I don't know whether it is awkward to normal behavior of cells or not,it seems as if it is so!Hence I am giving it up to some one who can answer, apologize if any thing stupid in asking this question.Normally,when we touch a table view cell,what happens is it navigates to a view controller/a controller that is coded.Now what's strange here is it is not responding to selection,or touch.I have checked whether or not allows selection while editing is selected in IB or not.I have selected it,now the twist here is when I am touching a table view cell it is not responding,instead when I swipe it horizontally/when I long press the cell,it is navigating,really surprised at this strange behavior!I don't understand the reason why I need to swipe it to make selection of cell in table view work.This is also happening with button present below the table view!

I have searched for issues similar to my case,but I found just one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326992/iphone-coding-problem-with-uitableview-selection) there it was suggested to check for this method,

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But i haven't implemented that method at all,what I have actually is a tab bar with several items,where I have a controller called AddController,for accessing several attributes and strings etc.. declared in the controller,I am subclassing it as follows:

```
@interface ViewController : AddController
```

Now because it was specified in the question I saw,i.e. the link I gave,to check whether u are copying the same code in subclass controller page,I spoke about subclassing and what I did,hope every one understands it!

Can any one please guide me how to get out of this issue,and make table view cell respond to normal touches,any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research I'm pretty sure that it is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the tableView caused you the problem. If you were like me having the text field in the cell and using the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to close the keyboard, here's my solution:

In the view that you implemented `UITextFieldDelegate`

(In my case I have a custom `UITableViewCell` called TextFieldCell),

Declare a `UITapGestureRecognizer` as a property:

```
@interface TextFieldCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *theTextField;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *theTextField;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
```

And initialize it in your view:

```
self.gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeKeyboard:)];
```

In the `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method, use `superView` to move up to your tableView and call `addGestureRecognizer`:

```
[self.superview.superview addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

And in the `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`, just remove the gesture recognizer:

```
[self.superview.superview removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

This will totally solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Hac.Jack,it worked and that was the problem,fixed it with the help of your code snippet,thanks a lot for the concern :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you use a UITapGestureRecognizer on your tableView? I had the exactly same problem as you did today, and then I figured out that it was the gesture recognizer that blurs my intention for selecting a row by tapping. When I removed it, the tableView was back to normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I used "UITapGestureRecognizer" Mr..Hac Jack.Glad that you speculated it spot on,yes by implementing ur code,I was able to eliminate the problem,thank u thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad it fixed for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by ticking "Scrolling Enabled" in the table view attributes.

My table view doesn't need scrolling, so it doesn't affect the app in any other way, except now I don't get the first unresponsive tap after a swipe gesture.